# PhD in Nanomaterials

Tags: research-process, second-degree

I am a doctoral student in metallurgy (joined 2014- about to finish it by July 2017) having my background of B.Tech Electrical and MS in nanoscience.

I wish to pursue my another doctoral degree in nanomaterials, Is it advisable to go for it.

I have some offers from abroad in prestigious institutes too. Is it good to go for it?.

Comment: Generally, you get only one Ph.D., then (if desired) a postdoc in the second area.  Two Ph.D.s is not unheard of, but WHY?